# Multiple Gallery Slider in a Single WordPress Page

Tags: wordpress, slider, image-gallery, nextgen-gallery

I would like to ask if anyone has recommendations for multiple gallery slider in a single wordpress page?

I am looking for this type of plugin and found that most sliders when duplicated in a single page, will return similar images from the wordpress library.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: make your own. There are loads of tutorials on things like this.

Comment: @David Thanks. I will try other methods.